# What age ranges constitute a "tender-age child?"

Tags: meaning

Hollywood police procedurals frequently show officers calling for support or emergency medical attention for "*tender-age* children," but I can't find a good definition of what ages that phrase is supposed to encompass.

(Closest I found was a possible origin for the phrase in the common-law "[tender years doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tender_years_doctrine)", but the age ranges encompassed by that vary drastically by jurisdiction, and it seems disconnected from common usage of the phrase in question.)

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think there is an “official”  definition of tender age in terms of what exact age it refers to. Most main dictionaries define  [tender age](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/tender-age-shelters/story?id=56028638) as:

> a time in your life when you are still young and lack experience.

It appears that tender age limits are defined according to context, for instance during recent episodes of detention centers along the U.S. southern border with Mexico, the following article from [ABC](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/tender-age-shelters/story?id=56028638) says:

***What classifies a child as 'tender age'?***

> Border Patrol officials said children under 5 fall under the definition of "tender age."
>
> Border Patrol chiefs in the field have generally referred to children "of less than 5 being tender age," Hastings said.
>
> ***But according to an official from the Department of Health and Human Services, a "tender age" child can be up to 13 years old.***
>
> "We have specialized facilities that are devoted to providing care for children with special needs and tender age children as we define as under 13 would fall into that category," Steve Wagner, HHS Acting Assistant Secretary, Administration for Children and Families told reporters Tuesday.

Answer (score 2):

Children 0-13 years old are considered tender age. In reference to user 66974's post, I work with detention centers and that is the range that we refer to as TA.

Comment: I would include this level of personal knowledge to be sufficient authority.

Comment: Yes, but this gives a (ie one) stipulative definition rather than a dictionary definition. The term in general usage is ill-defined.